# pentaho PDI passing uservariable in command line

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to run a Transformation/Job by passing a user variable in command line.
I have tried by passing variable value as below.

**sh pan.sh -file='test.ktr' '-param:input_directory=/path/to/directory' -level=basic**
where input_directory is variable in transformation and i mentioned it as **${input_directory}**

But when I do this, the pan is unable to find the variable value. It is throwing error as below

**Could not list the contents of "file:///home/user1/pdi8.1/data-integration8.1/${input_directory}" because it is not a folder.**

can someone help me on this. Thank you

Comment: Since this is linux, have you tried without quotes? i.e. -param:input_directory=/path Also, have you defined this as a named parameter of the transformation?

Comment: Thank you ..I have tried without quotes like **-file='Events.ktr'  -param:input_directory=samplefiles -level=debug** Still same error..I have defined it as **${input_directory}** and i am not setting anything except passing parameteer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass named parameters to your job or transformation, the parameters need to be defined in the properties window, shown here for a transformation. The default value is not needed, but works well for testing. Pay attention to capitalization.

[image]

So the pieces of the puzzle are:

1. From the command line, pass the parameter like -param:yourparam=yourvalue
2. Define this same parameter in the highest-level job or transformation
3. Use it as you would use any variable, with ${yourparam}

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. How can I pass this value in the Linux command line?

Comment: The way you already are, with -param:input_directory=/path/to/directory The trick is that you can't just pass the param and then use it like a variable without defining it first.

Comment: Let me tell you what i did, and pls correct me if i am wrong. first I have defined a variable in get files component 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mm2Ye2dGP8uq6joGTc3KZTTzw5zP5M__
Then I am passing this variable from linux command line..Is there anything i am doing it wrongly.

Comment: Your are missing a $ in front of the variable

Comment: It was a missing while i am taking the screenshot inorder to remove client's names/directorirs(which included names). But I tried with **$**. I got the error.

Comment: When I tried by passing the same parameter in UI and ran the job. But now. I have included **set Variable** component in the job. it was successful. When I try the same on Linux command line it was the same error I got.

Answer (score 0):

i think the parameter names to be used in job should be ${PARAM_NAME1}
using command line i follow the below convention 
call "{Replace with kitchen.bat File Path}" /file:"{Replace with JOB File Path}"  "-param:PARAM_NAME1=PARAM_VALUE1" "-param:PARAM_NAME2=PARAM_VALUE2"